# IE-11 does not send preflight OPTIONS request

Tags: cors, ie11-developer-tools

I am seeing preflight OPTIONS request is not being sent from IE-11 browser while doing a cross domain call. First request is sent is handshake request only.
What are the cases when IE-11 does and does not send preflight OPTIONS request ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: Did anyone get a chance to look at this ?

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem? Did you make it work for Chrome/Firefox/Safari?
I have the same issue?

Comment: In My case it works fine fore Chrome and Firefox. (Safari: not tested). But still does not work for IE-11.